# Django session IDs for anonymous sessions

Tags: django, django-sessions

I see that a random (but not necessarily unique) `session_key` is generated for new sessions and this is stored in whichever session type you're using (cache, db, cookie).

The two queries I have are:

1. Is a new `session_key` generated for all sessions, including anonymous ones
2. Does the expiry of the anonymous sessions follow the same duration as a authenticated one - i.e. following `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, even anonymous users get sessions.
2. Yes. The documentation doesn't say much about the expiration of anonymous sessions but I am presuming it would follow the same rules.